# How do I use the Grails Debug Toolbar Plugin?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I've installed the Debug Toolbar plugin for Grails ( http://grails.org/plugin/debug-toolbar ) and am having some trouble getting it to display.  Here are the steps that I've performed so far...

1. added the following code to my application's header

   <debugToolbar:renderMe/>
2. set the following variable in Config.groovy's 'environments' method (in the 'development' subsection)

   debugToolbar.enabled = true

When I run the app I don't see the toolbar.  What am I missing?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the  tag needs to be in the body